Ruby on Rails app ID sequence gets out of order all the time
I have a Ruby on Rails app using a Heroku Postgres database. When I create new records for any model, the id's get out of sequence constantly. They usually skip about 30 id's. I know how to reset the sequence, but the question is, why does this happen so frequently? Anyone seen / fixed this before?

Probably failed transactions or the setting for CACHE. But it's pretty normal to have gaps, don't worry about it or don't use a sequence at all.

I've never seen this, and it's not normal. If you can reproduce the anomaly, looking at production.log should yield some insight
